# Unity - Declaring a bool variable in abstract class doesn't return as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public abstract class Condition
{
 [SerializeField] protected string parameter;
 public string Parameter => parameter;
 protected bool conditionMet = false;
 public bool ConditionMet => conditionMet;
 public abstract void CheckCondition(string eventMessage);


}

[System.Serializable]
public class IntCondition : Condition
{

 [SerializeField] private NumberComparisonType comparison;
 [SerializeField] private int expectedInt;
    

 public override void CheckCondition(string eventMessage)
 {
     int count = int.Parse(eventMessage.Split(':')[1]);
     if (comparison == NumberComparisonType.GreaterOrEqual)
     {
         if (count >= expectedInt)
             conditionMet = true;
         else
             conditionMet = false;

     }
     else if (comparison == NumberComparisonType.Less)
     {
         if (count < expectedInt)
             conditionMet = true;
         else
             conditionMet = false;
     }
 }

}
```

I am trying to create conditions for my Quest System in Unity. Even though I set conditionMet=false in the beginning, when I call the ConditionMet property, it returns true. The only way to make it work is to use [SerializeField] and making it false from the Unity inspector. How can I make this false default without having to use Unity inspector? Is this a problem about abstract classes?

Edit: This script is used in a ScriptableObject. Can this be the reason? If it is, how can I overcome this problem?

Edit2: So it seems initial values inside Serializable classes are ignored. I have learned that now. But how can I overcome this?

Edit3: I am using this in a scriptableObject named "QuestData" and then creating Quest.cs using these QuestDatas. I noticed that changes I make in runtime, also affects the scriptable object, thus Condition script. So it saves the "conditionsMet" value. But I need it to not save the value.

Comment: [Boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean?view=net-5.0) is a structure so you shouldnt explicitly set it as false (just saying so you can save yourself some typing in the future). Otherwise your code seems okay. Are you sure `CheckCondition` isn't called somewhere before you are calling the `ConditionMet` property? Maybe include the code where you are using these classes

Comment: FYI: `conditionMet = count >= expectedInt;` and `conditionMet = count < expectedInt;`

Comment: @JochemVanHespen Thanks for the response. Yes I have checked. CheckCondition is not called. Even if it was, it would be false too. As I said if I make conditionsMet a SerializedField and set it from Unity inspector, everything works fine. But I don't understand how setting it from inspector and setting it like above any different.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the CheckCondition method and see if it hits. Make your variable a property with a custom get and set a breakpoint there too to check the state of your class. Your code doesn't seem to have any issues so I'm quite confused as well.

Comment: @MajdOdeh I put a Debug.Log at the start of the CheckConditions() method. It is not getting called when I start the game. So it is not about the method. I believe this is something about the abstract classes.

Comment: By the way this script is used in a ScriptableObject. Can this be the reason? If it is, how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: So it seems initial values inside Serializable classes are ignored. I have learned that now. But how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a MonoBehaviour, what you can do is to implement a constructor and set the default values there:

```
public Condition()
{
    parameter = string.Empty();
    conditionMet = false;
}
```

And then a Constructor for your IntCondition

```
public IntCondition() : base() {}
```

When you instantiate your DerivedCondition, it will construct and set the default values for you, so you don't need to make it a SerializeField and set the values in the Inspector

Comment: But I need to be able to set parameter value from the inspector. If I do what you suggest, I won't be able to change parameter value from inspector.

Comment: I am using this in a scriptableObject named "QuestData" and then creating Quest.cs using these QuestDatas. I noticed that changes I make in runtime, also affects the scriptable object, thus Condition script. So it saves the "conditionsMet" value. But I need it to not save the value.

Comment: Then you probably need to think about a refactor. Do you actually need the conditionMet variable or can you replace it using a sentence (e.g. bool ConditionMet(expected) => parameter == expected;)

Comment: I changed it completely. I gave up on ScriptableObject and used prefabs. Now the system is working fine. Apparently, scriptable objects don't reset its values on the editor. That was the problem all along.